# How Ι can unpublish one menu item (default item) from the menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, administration

Hi Joomla community Ι need help . I have one item in my main menu (default item menu) and Ι want to unpublished this item.

When I hit the Unpublish button it shows me an error:

> Error Can't unpublish default home

Answer (score 3):

Joomla requires a home menu item to be set. The error message you get states exactly this. You can't unpublish the default home menu item.

The thing here is what you want to do and why. Why you would want to unpublish the home menu item?

Usually if you want to have a different home page, you can just change the settings of the current home menu item.

But if you really want to unpublish the current home menu item, then first you need to specify another menu item as the default (home menu item) and then unpublish it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't unpublish the home menu item but you can hide it.

Create a new menu an assign it to an unplublished menu module and then transfer the home menu item to the new menu.

Comment: That's a good tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unpublish the home menu.
Create another menu assigned in to default then you can unpublish the home menu item.